# How to use bridges on tails?

Tags: tails

I received obsf4 bridges off of the tor site.
When inserting them into the tor configuration screen when tails boots up,
Tails is then stuck on "Connected to Bridge".
The error that is given in the logs is "Generic Proxy Server Error"
How can I fix this?
Log :https://pastebin.com/raw/VNcvkWUT
Images: https://ibb.co/hd1QXGV
https://ibb.co/mHc7PHs  https://ibb.co/12cMXLP

Answer (score 0):

Set your time to london time.
Timezone is defaulted to london but the system clock does not synchronize without tor enabled.